# dropdown menu with jquery second level

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a vertical dropdown menu with jquery and I can't figure out why is this happening.

First level sub menu works fine, but second level (sub sub) is doing something strange - it slides up!

Just check this and click on 2222 sub menu:

https://jsfiddle.net/adam900/ba3d7bu0/9/

```js
//jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav ul li").has("> .sub-nav").click(function() {
    $(this).find("> .sub-nav").stop().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/*CSS*/
#nav ul {
  display: inline-table;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
}
#nav .sub-nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">11111</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">11111 &darr;</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="#">2222</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2222 &darr;</a>
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#">333333</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">333333</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">11111</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can you please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **[stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav ul li").has("> .sub-nav").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find("> .sub-nav").stop().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba3d7bu0/12/)**

Answer (score 0):

The click handler is executed twice for nested li elements. Use

```
 e.stopPropagation();
```

to prevent the event from bubbling up.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav ul li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find("> .sub-nav").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#nav ul {
  display: inline-table;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#nav li a {
  display: block;
}
#nav .sub-nav {
  display: none;
}
#nav > ul li a {
  padding: 16px 20px 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">11111</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">11111 &darr;</a>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="#">2222</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">2222 &darr;</a>
          <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="#">333333</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">333333</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">11111</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```